How to count area of RGeo::Geographic::SphericalMultiPolygonImpl?
I have data such as
<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalMultiPolygonImpl:0x30b38 "MULTIPOLYGON (((32.038193 49.465447, 31.996651 49.434199, 32.02549 49.416781, 32.00489 49.398016, 32.069092 49.365831, 32.103081 49.390642, 32.147026 49.364713, 32.172775 49.378797, 32.153549 49.386619, 32.14325 49.404942, 32.112007 49.415217, 32.096214 49.442906, 32.038193 49.465447)))"> 

I tried to do something like this:
    projected_factory = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory

    projected_shape = RGeo::Feature.cast(multipolygon, factory: projected_factory)
    area = projected_shape.area

but it seems there are significant inaccuracies.
and now I can't understand how to calculate the area.
